# Converting String element to Integer java

Tags: java

I am writing a method which takes in a .txt file and adds the information to a Student type, which has String name and int age, weight and height. I load in all the data, splitting by a comma. To convert the string to int I am trying to use Integer.pareseInt(), but this code seems to be causing an error, what might be causing this?

```
    public static StudentCollection loadBespoke(File file){
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader b_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
        String line;
        while((line = b_reader.readLine())!= null){
            String[] items = line.split(",");
            String name = items[0];
            System.out.println(items[1]);

        
            int age = Integer.parseInt(items[1]); //errors
            int weight  = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);
            int height = Integer.parseInt(items[3]);

            Student student = new Student();
            student.withName(name);
            student.withAge(age);
            student.withWeight(weight);
            student.withHeight(height);

            students.add(student);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return new StudentCollection(students);
}
```

The .txt looks like this:
Benjamin, 20, 63, null
Sarah, 19, 53, 165

And the error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 20"

Comment: Could you please paste the error also here? It will because of null value is file. You can check for null first and parse it to int.

Comment: Try to write items[1].trim() - which removes the whitespaces. But I guess your code will still fail because items[3] seems be "null" (the string "null", nut actually null - but that doesn't matter since both will not be parsed correctly).

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsin I try to debug by stepping through and printing to the console, I can see that items[1] indeed prints out 20

Comment: It prints out as " 20", with a space in front of the 20. That is (one of) your problem(s).

Comment: `" 20"` starts with a space, and [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) doesn't allow spaces, so do as Florian suggested, call `trim()`. --- Next time, **read the documentation**, i.e. the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), which explains what input is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces between elements or trim the items `Integer.parseInt(items[1].trim())`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure items[1] has no space or tab to it.. try printing its value.. in Java you can trim using trim() method